# Is it possible to suffer from frostbite and sunburn simultaneously?

Tags: magic, magical-creatures, my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony, unicorns

In the most recent episode of My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic, Rarity makes the [amusing claim](http://youtu.be/ft1rbnlYhYY) that she has given the townsfolk both frostbite and sunburn both in rapid succession, due to her poor skill at controlling the weather (which is a fairly ordinary power in their universe).

Is this actually possible, though?  From my understanding, both frostbite and sunburn involve the destruction of skill cells, to the point that they are irreparable and must be healed by being replaced.  It seems that they may in fact be mutually exclusive - one could not damage cells in one way which have already been destroyed in another.

Naturally, there is limited real-world experience to draw from, due to the extreme environment and scenario that would have to be created to test this, limiting the idea exclusively to the realm of magic and super-science.

Comment: Are you talking about ponies getting frostbite/sunburn or humans?

Comment: Why are you assuming that the same cells are being damaged with each problem?  It seems reasonable for me to have frostbite on my fingers, but sunburn on my shoulders.

Comment: @CamelBlues Humans, mainly, although you can discuss it as broadly as you wish.

Comment: @AdeleC Well, in the example, it was mostly full-body for both, what with the ponies being naked and all.

Comment: I believe floating unprotected in the vacuum of space would give you both frostbite and sunburn simultaneously.

Comment: **Why** is the question about humans? Are there humans in the *My Little Pony* universe? Can ponies get sunburn?

Comment: @user14111 The question is about how this phenomenon applies to the real world, and whether or not it's actually possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible; it's pretty unlikely in the real world, though it does happen in extreme cases, but magically induced weather could easily create the conditions needed for both.

Frostbite is caused by the skin being exposed to long-term below-freezing temperatures. It goes through several stages, only the last of which causes permanent tissue death. Under extremely cold conditions, third-degree frostbite can happen in as little as fifteen minutes, and mild frostbite ("frostnip") can take as little as a minute.

Sunburn is cause by ultraviolet radiation damaging the DNA of skin cells, which the body responds to (in part) by increasing the melanin on the skin to block further radiation, and trying to repair the damage. The sunburn itself doesn't actually destroy much skin tissue (the pain comes from other things) and in fact can trigger melanomas -- *overproduction* of skin cells.

To get both sunburn and frostbite merely requires a very cold atmosphere under extremely bright sun. Snow-covered regions like mountains and glaciers are particularly suitable for this, as the snow reflects extra sunlight back onto the skin. Of course, even thin layers of clothes will prevent sunburn, so it's usually an accident when someone is exposed to both conditions at the same time.

But, if the weather conditions were to suddenly, magically shift from temperate to simultaneously really bright *and* really cold, sunburn/frostbite would definitely result.

Comment: Presumably weather control magic could also influence the ozone layer (or that world's equivalent), so that the proportion of UV reaching the surface increases (even if overall brightness does not increase much).

Answer (score 9):

It is most certainly possible to become sunburned AND frostbitten at the same time. Skiers are often susceptible to sunburn as addressed [in this article](http://sports.yahoo.com/top/news?slug=ycn-10366479).

Sunburn does not require a specific temperature, it requires certain types of UV rays. Frostbite, however, does require cold temperatures (which could simply be generated by wind).

Granted, this is for humans. What sort of UV rays exist in My-Little-Pony-Land (is the whole planet called Equestria? I forget.) - or what susceptibility to sunburn ponies have would change how likely it is for the *ponies* to become sunburned *and* frostbitten, but the science is valid enough.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Equestria is only their country, as implied in Hearth's Warming Eve.  Thanks for the answer, btw!

Answer (score 1):

According to [Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/antarctica/practical-information/health) both conditions are risks that people travelling to Antarctica may be exposed to.

> Frostbite is most likely to occur in the nose, cheeks, chin, fingers, and toes. The first sign is numbness and redness, followed by the development of a waxy, white or yellow plaque. Severe frostbite may lead to blisters, gangrene and loss of the affected body part.

And:

> Even on overcast days, it’s easy to get sunburned quickly, since the sun reflects off snow, ice and the sea. Use sunscreen with SPF 15 or higher. Calamine lotion relieves mild sunburn.

Obviously this isn't limited "exclusively to the realm of magic and super-science" but is something that can and does happen in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in mountains at high altitude where atmosphere starts becoming thin and air gets scarce. The temperature is raised due to altitude and wind is chilling due to snow around. Thus keeping exposed in sun as well as shadow like half of your body is  sun and rest half in shadow will definitely cause sun burn and cold as well.

Comment: Temperature is 'raised due to altitude' -- Huh ?!.  Are you saying that the temperature increases with altitude ?  If so, that would be news to lots of mountain climbers.